# How to apply wordpress/php function to a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Re. Wordpress, WooCommerce, Woo Subscriptions

I want to use the below function (https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8851287) to hide certain 'action' buttons, but I only want to apply this to one category of my wordpress products.

How might I do this?

```
<?php
 * Remove the "Change Payment Method" button from the My Subscriptions table.
 *
 * This isn't actually necessary because @see eg_subscription_payment_method_cannot_be_changed()
 * will prevent the button being displayed, however, it is included here as an example of how to
 * remove just the button but allow the change payment method process.
 */
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
    foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
        switch ( $action_key ) {
            case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
//          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
//          case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
//          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
//          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
//          case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
//          case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                break;
            default: 
                error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                break;
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions',     'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

More info:

The page in question is the view-subscription page that comes with WooCommerce Subscriptions: /mysite/my-account/view-subscription/4606/

The suggestions below are based on capturing the current category ID, for example:

```
$cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id; // get current category id).
```

I worry this will not work because we're actually looking at a Woocommerce subscription management page, and NOT the actual Woocommerce product page (which would have a category).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button( $actions, $subscription ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id; // get current category id

    if($cat_id == 26) { // check if we're in the category
                foreach ( $actions as $action_key => $action ) {
            switch ( $action_key ) {
                case 'change_payment_method':   // Hide "Change Payment Method" button?
    //          case 'change_address':      // Hide "Change Address" button?
    //          case 'switch':          // Hide "Switch Subscription" button?
    //          case 'resubscribe':     // Hide "Resubscribe" button from an expired or cancelled subscription?
    //          case 'pay':         // Hide "Pay" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold" as they require payment?
    //          case 'reactivate':      // Hide "Reactive" button on subscriptions that are "on-hold"?
    //          case 'cancel':          // Hide "Cancel" button on subscriptions that are "active" or "on-hold"?
                    unset( $actions[ $action_key ] );
                    break;
                default: 
                    error_log( '-- $action = ' . print_r( $action, true ) );
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'eg_remove_my_subscriptions_button', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: That you Zipkundan.  Unfortunately this does not work.  The code works if I remove the if statement, so I think perhaps the category ID is not being returned to the function correctly.  Should I consider targeting a specific product ID instead of a category ID?

Comment: (repeated) I added a bit more info to the original description.  I fear that because the page displaying the buttons is related to the woocommerce subscription/order, the category of the original product will not be available.